# String java startsWith

Tags: java, string, startswith

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        String s1 = "/program/rest/user/forgotPwd/";
        String s2 = "/program/rest/user/forgetPwd/test";
        System.out.println(s1.startsWith(s2));
        System.out.println(s2.startsWith(s1));
    }
}
```

Both the cases print `false`. Any explanations?

Comment: Please next time look closer...

Comment: you should voteup all the answers since everybody has given right answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings are not as identical as you think. The first string contains `forgotPwd` while the second contains `forgetPwd`.

Answer (score 2):

because in 1st string you are having `forgotPwd`  and in second `forgetPwd` . Difference is `o` and `e`

Answer (score 1):

Your s1 is not a part of s2. `forgotPwd`

Check this.

```
String s1 = "/program/rest/user/forgotPwd/";
String s2 = "/program/rest/user/forgotPwd/test";
System.out.println(s1.startsWith(s2));
System.out.println(s2.startsWith(s1));
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

case 1 is obvious.
case 2 is false because s1 has "forgot" and s2 has "forget".

Answer (score 1):

That's natural. Look closer at your strings.

```
String s1 = "/program/rest/user/forgotPwd/";
String s2 = "/program/rest/user/forgetPwd/test";
```

s1 has the word `forgotPwd`, s2 has `forgetPwd`. There is 1 letter difference.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in *s2* it says:

> String s2 = "/program/rest/user/forgetPwd/test";

and it should say:

> String s2 = "/program/rest/user/forgotPwd/test";

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try specifying an index of the form

```
        "Foobar".startsWith("bar", 3)
```

which returns true. After checking your typos of course.